# Cannot click on radio button - Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I cannot interact with the input element to select the first radio button.

[image: This is the DOM]

Below is what I've tried by far;

```js
export function clickOnMediaAutoLevel(level) {
  // button is not clickable without force: true, it is set to hidden in the CSS
  cy.get(locators.screen)
    .within(($screen) => {
      cy.get('div.radio-buttons')
      .contains('Media Audio Level')
      .find('input')
      .click( { force: true } )
    })
  cy.pause()        
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is happening? Are there any errors on the console? And how does the HTML looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.check()` no `.click()`. Source - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check.html#Syntax

Comment: Yes, for radio/checkbox, we can properly use check() instead of click(). Works for disabled elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your input has a prop "hidden" and it is possible that it prevents firing of that event (like a prop "disabled" would do).

> The hidden global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can't be used until the login process has been completed. **Browsers won't render elements with the hidden attribute set.**
>
> **The hidden attribute must not be used to hide content just from one presentation. If something is marked hidden, it is hidden from all presentations, including, for instance, screen readers.**
>
> Hidden elements shouldn't be linked from non-hidden elements, and elements that are descendants of a hidden element are still active, which means that script elements can still execute and form elements can still submit. **Elements and scripts may, however, refer to elements that are hidden in other contexts.**
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden

Try to mimic clicking on the label, because right now you don't click input itself in an application. You should consider removing a "hidden" prop completely in that context.